# Get data from DB based and display in textbox on selected values. laravel 5.7

Tags: mysql, laravel

I had to display data on textbox on change of select box but it will not work & also control not going to ajax url.

HTMl code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="product_title" id="product_title">
    @foreach($product_title as $id => $p_title )
     <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $p_title }}</option>
      @endforeach                                       
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_price" id="product_price">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity">
```

Js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#product_title").change(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
               $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                  }
              });
         jQuery.ajax({
                  url: "{{ url('/productdetails') }}",
                  method: 'get',
                  data: {
                     id: jQuery('#product_title').val()
                  },
                  success: function(result){
                    jQuery('#product_price').html(result.product_price);
                    jQuery('#product_quantity').html(result.product_quantity);

                  }});

  });
 });
</script>
```

route:
Route::get('/productdetails', 'ProductController@getProduct');

```
  public function getProduct(Request $req)
   {
       $product = product::find($req->id)->first(); // Product is the model
       //dd($product);
       if ($product) 
       {
        return response()->json(['product_price' => $product->product_price,'product_quantity' => $product->product_quantity]);
       }
  }
```

Database table name is product with attribute id,product_title,product_price,quantity.When i select title value from select box related value product_price,quantity from database will display in textbox.

Comment: Maybe you can explain the thing the you want in more detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issue is on success function lines. `html` is not useful for assign value to text. it is used to echo html. instead you can use `val()` like following.

`jQuery('#product_price').val(result.product_price);
 jQuery('#product_quantity').val(result.product_quantity);`

Hope it helps. happy coding.

Comment: you mean to say ajax is not going inside controller method ? can you dd product there in controller ?

Comment: control is not passed in ajax coding so error will not getting

Comment: Okay. what is result in `dd($product)` inside controller method ? if you are not getting `$product` than probably ajax won't give you any response. can you try somethin like `else { return response()->json([ 'status' => 'response not found' ] , 200) }` after your if condition and check for it.

Comment: hello,problem is in ajax coding. Why control is not reached to jquery.ajax.......

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '#product_title', function(e)  { e.preventDefault()  })`  have you tried like this instead of current change code ?

Comment: thanks ajax works but it fetch only first record need change in coding plz suggest

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple without jquery like as follow

```
<select>
foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
  echo "<option value=".$your_id_variable.">".$your_display_variable."</option>";
}
```